# how to raise a exception in clojure pre-expr?

Tags: clojure, pre

clojure's pre-expr seems cool, but does it possible if I want to raise an Exception when the `:pre` is false?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Dire](https://github.com/MichaelDrogalis/dire#preconditions) instead

```
(ns mytask
  (:require [dire.core :refer [with-precondition! with-handler!]]))

(defn add-one [n]
  (inc n))

(with-precondition! #'add-one
  "An optional docstring."
  ;;; Name of the precondition
  :not-two
  (fn [n & args]
    (not= n 2)))

(with-handler! #'add-one
  {:precondition :not-two}
  (fn [e & args] (apply str "Precondition failure for argument list: " (vector args))))

(add-one 2) ; => "Precondition failure for argument list: (2)"
```

Answer (score 1):

Preconditions are conditions that must be true or else an exception is thrown. If you have a condition where you want an exception to be thrown when false, just `complement` the conditional or `not` the result.

```
user=> (defn magic? [n] (= 0 (rem n 42)))
#'user/magic?
```

---

```
user=> (defn foo [n] {:pre [(magic? n)]} n)
#'user/foo
user=> (foo 42)
42
```

---

```
user=> (defn bar [n] {:pre [(not (magic? n))]} n)
#'user/bar

user=> (bar 42)
AssertionError Assert failed: (not (magic? n))  user/bar
```

---

```
user=> (defn baz [n] {:pre [((complement magic?) n)]} n)
#'user/baz
user=> (baz 42)

AssertionError Assert failed: ((complement magic?) n)  user/baz
```